# Signaling protocol detection using wireshark

Tags: sip, wireshark, rtp, tshark

I have many .pcap files each of 500MB. I have run many tshark commands to find the existence of SIP, RTP, H323 packets in those .pcac files. but I only found RTP packets. I know there is audio in this data thats why RTP packets are there, but i am unable to find which protocol is used for signaling as there is no SIP or H323 packets.

I can open the file and seach for the port no. of RTP but as the files are large in number and size i cannot do so.

Please suggest something which can be done to find the protocol used for signaling.

Is there any tshark command which detects any type of signaling data ?
Or any list of commands which i should execute.

Comment: Not sure what you need. Find the RTP endpoints (IP+ports in RTP communication)? or find the signaling protocol used to negotiate the communication? or find the codec used for RTP?

Comment: i dont know what protocol is used for signaling of RTP data. One way is :
1) opening the file and finding the RTP-Port by ctrl+f and see what protocol is it, but file size and the number of files is too large. So i need a command for the same

Comment: i have extracted all info about the RTP packets- IP PORT CODEC etc by a tshark command, I want a similar command for finding signalling info